# mouseenter/mouseleave div expand

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

I need to expand a div when the mouse over that, that occur pretty well but when the mouse leave the div doesn't get back to normal

heres some come and my file http://jsfiddle.net/MyKnB/

```
$("#logo-expand").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "56px;"
    }, 300 );
});

$("#logo-expand").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "170px"
    }, 300 );
});
```

Comment: `$("#logo-expand").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {$(this).animate({width:(e.type=='mouseenter'?56:170)},300);});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the `;` after `56px`. If you change that line to `width: "56px"` instead, it works properly. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/MyKnB/1/

Comment: works but not quite well, because every time I take the cursor to another div it supposed to get back normal and it stays expanded...

Comment: @paoloi Is the other `div` within `#logo-expand`?